# How to make my iPhone less reactive

Tags: iphone, ios

I have my iPhone in my hand when I am running. And it reacts a lot for shakes or touches on the display and I feel it a little annoying. How should I keep it less reactive? I don't want to turn it off since I am usually on listening to podcasts.

Comment: Have you considered one of those armband carriers? probably safer, you might drop it...

Comment: I don't like armbands that much. My iPhone is protected with a case so it's ok. Thanks, though.

Comment: Failing your preference for an armband and if you don't have pockets in your running gear, your choices are limited to *something* that will attach the phone to your body, a clip or band that clips onto some part of your clothing or goes around one ore more parts of your body. Unless you want an Apple Watch and some wireless earbuds.